# single database, apps on different platform, best method?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, database, parse-platform

sorry i am totally a new to this.
I am making a app and i want to make it cross platform.
there will be a single database.
I want to know how it can be done?
Some of things keeping in mind:

1. Its a business app so no security compromise.
2. No glitch in using app
3. there will be lots of notifications

thanks

Comment: you can use remote db with service integration and gcm

Comment: hi thanks for replying but i am looking for detailed answer

Comment: ok basically u will need to discide technology first i mean webservice and all

Comment: yeah if you can help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option (what I use) is to have a [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) server that handles storing the data. In my case, I have an [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) server that has an SQL database on it with a phpmyAdmin interface set up.

The benefit of having a RESTful interface is that it's pretty universal. Pretty much any platforms can make requests to it in similar ways. I'd definitely recommend that.

If you want to send push notifications, you'll also need a server of your own. I personally use the same server I mentioned above.

For security purposes, you'll want to use an SSL certificate on your server, have the user log in, use a token, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best idea would be using a **WebService** to store and provide data. 
So your solutions on differents plataforms and devices could just **send requests** to your WebService. 
I would recomend the **JSON** instead XML for the requests, because JSON isn't heavy like XML and it has a SIMPLE SIMPLE formatting pattern.

By the way, if you don't want that your application have a networking need, you'll have to retrieve data and store on your devices/plataforms (and it could be a problem). So you'll have a work a little harder if two people modify the same data, think about: 
 Me -> Receive Data Person{Name=Felipe,Age=20} -> Modify Person{Name=**FelipeMoraes**,Age=20}
You -> Receive Data Person{Name=Felipe,Age=20} -> Modify Person{Name=**FelipeUser**,Age=20}

If you are working out with shared informations (informations that more than one person could edit) you could attend yourself about this, like locking the record or comparing the newest and the modifications (hard part, I guess).

Take a look about this integration architecture, it's simplified:
[image]

And take a look at some detailed articles: 
http://www.themobilemontage.com/2012/11/29/successfully-integrating-web-services-into-your-android-apps/ 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-service-start-to-finish--net-22264